# org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have created a hibernate session and started a transaction for that session.

After that, multiple calls to a stored procedure are made one by one in that session. In one of the calls I have got this error

> org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not extract ResultSet

After all the procedure calls, transaction is committed.

What should happen in this case ?

What I have observed is that only some entries(related to the stored procedure calls) are reflecting in the MySQL Database while others are not.

Shouldn't the ideal behaviour be that all the entries reflect in the database except that of the failed call to stored procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I am not able to understand what really you meant. Still I would like to state some points in case they can help you.

1. Ideally what happens is that every database communication is made inside a transaction.
2. A session in hibernate is a not a threadsafe object and is discared after every communication with the database. A Session will not obtain a JDBC Connection, or a Datasource, unless it is needed. It will not consume any resources until used.
3. If in case any error/exception occurs inside a transaction then the whole transaction is rolled back in the ideal case.

In case  you have nested transactions

```
What happens depends on whether this is a nested transaction:

If it is not, then eventually the transaction times out and rolls back.
If it is, the parent transaction will see that a child transaction has not committed when it commits itself. This will result in a rollback of the entire transaction.
```